# display div elements in parent with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with class `container`. I have 3 more `divs` inside `.container`. What I want is to display internal divs `float: left` so that 2 divs tags are visible inside `.container` and the third one is invisible and is placed on the right side of first 2 div tags which are visible. I am trying the following code but it makes all tags visible all the time.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doforumda/nftp6/)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.container {
            position: relative;
            width: 405px;
            height: 500px;
            background: red;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: blue;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

I want above to look like this

[image]

Comment: increase the width of .container. It have only 405px as width. child div tag have 200px as width, 2 div occupies 400px. then how 3rd one will display?

Comment: I want the 3rd div to be not shown. I will later add `next` button so when clicking next button the first div will move towards left and will become invisible and the third will become visible.

Comment: reduce width of the .container class upto you reach your goal

Comment: Check my modified answer.

Comment: @2619 did you check other answer's besides Ashis'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as such in other way,

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 405px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.innerContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 605px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Check over here http://jsfiddle.net/nftp6/8/

Comment: @2619 In your design, the third one is partially visible. If you want in that way, check this http://jsfiddle.net/nftp6/10/.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
```

For that effect

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/nftp6/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of float and set `white-space:nowrap` to the container:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 405px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/nftp6/4/)**

Now you'll most likely face some white-space issues, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/2049063) for multiple ways to handle that